# Update the visualization of a set of geometries on Open3D in Non-Blocking mode

Tags: python, visualization, nonblocking, open3d

I'm trying to update a set of geometries on `open3d==0.12.0` using `vis.update_geometry(geometry)` that updates a single geometry. However, the current solution is a bit slow compared to `open3d==0.7.0` using `vis.update_geometry()` that updates all the geometries.
Is there any other solution? Here is my current solution:

```
import open3d as o3d

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Create Open3d visualization window
    vis = o3d.visualization.Visualizer()
    vis.create_window()
    vis.create_window("BASSAR")
    vis.get_render_option().background_color = [0.75, 0.75, 0.75]
    vis.get_render_option().mesh_show_back_face = True

    # adding geometries : 
    for g in geometries:
        vis.add_geometry(g)

    while True:
        # updating geometries:
        # ...
        
        for g in geometries:
            vis.update_geometry(g)

        vis.poll_events()
        vis.update_renderer()
```

Comment: try `vis.update_renderer()` in the loop

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize it first. Then, update it like this:

```
import open3d as o3d

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Create Open3d visualization window
    vis = o3d.visualization.Visualizer()
    vis.create_window()
    # initialization
    pointcloud = o3d.geometry.PointCloud()
    vis.add_geometry(pointcloud)

    vis.create_window("BASSAR")
    vis.get_render_option().background_color = [0.75, 0.75, 0.75]
    vis.get_render_option().mesh_show_back_face = True

    # adding geometries : 
    for g in geometries:
        vis.add_geometry(g)

    while True:
        # updating geometries:
        # ...
        
        for g in geometries:
            # update
            pointcloud.points = g.points
            vis.update_geometry(pointcloud)

        vis.poll_events()
        vis.update_renderer()
```